# python urlopen opens faster with slower internet?

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to make a program that will read a webpage from a website. The data to be read is only 18kb. I have a college wifi connection which is really fast (2 mbps) and has a proxy server running.

When I try to run the code:

```
import urllib
data=urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
```

it takes about 8 to 10 second to run (the same link opens really fast in web-browser)

however, when I run the same code on some other internet connection which is not as fast as the college wifi, the code runs in less than a second.

I am confused why it is slower on the wifi. Is this because of the proxy server? but if it is because of that, then why is the same link taking less time to open in the browser.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do not rely on similar test-tools. The real workload does not obey test-scenarios. Real production will suffer from other troubles -- network operator's poor-coordinated access-network NEXT/FEXT degradations in the co-existence of ADSL/VDSL/HDB3 signalling/line-code modulations, xDSL/DSLAM concentration policy, backbone network design / bottlenecks, service-level (non-)prioritised queuing.

Comment: sir, that was too much for me to digest in a single go. :P
Anyways, I do not understand what workload and production you are taking about. All I am saying is the same website opens quickly on browser (no cached pages involved) but does not open from urllib.urlopen().

Comment: The comment was related to a previous comment about using some speed-test ( that comment is now deleted ) and reflects the reasons, why web-based speed tests do not provide reliable results for further assumptions.

Comment: This is the code. This single line of code takes 10 secs

Comment: The code i neither **C**omplete, nor **V**erifiable.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to take a look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) instead of using plain `urllib`. Also, [pyquery](http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) may come handy depending on what you want to do with the page you read.

Answer (score 0):

### A: because of cached-pages

As a common feature, webBrowsers on their own + campus infrastructure ( as a perimeter transport reduction policy ) may benefit from cached-page storage, thus not waiting for an end-to-end transport delays associated with a distant server page-description retrieval.

Cached-pages get loaded instantly compared to the full reload of the page from the remote-server page

**After comment below on removal of cached pages:**

While a user is able to release localhost cache, the answer was talking about campus / ISP practices of infrastructure-based caching, that reduces the overall traffic across the access/backbone network and which is outside of end-user control.

**After OP was modified, to include the unambiguous URL-target:**

Having added your test goes against http-initiated session with www.google.com, you shall rather review the forward-rolling transactions, that happened to get started "under the hood" of this instruction. DNS resolution (if not cached) takes the same amount of time in browser/python, the redirection handshaking, encryption-services imports, encryption keys exchange handshaking and other imports/processing needed for a setup of http**S**-session are the next, hidden steps, that python as a universal language interpreter has to import/process ad-hoc, while browser is ready-to proceed as a specialised piece of software. You would see more details if using profiler ( from the processing-side traces / timing ) and/or network sniffer ( from the transport-side traces / timing ).

Comment: The present speed that i am receiving is 10.47Mbps. I have to download 18kb of data. It is taking me 10 secs to download. Do I really need a cached page to speed up download???

Comment: just to be sure, I removed all the cached files and images and still it takes a split second to load on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Download a 18kb file is not representative of your internet connection speed. With small file size, we're looking for an efficient latency.

Launch `urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com")` will make a lots of action behind the scene. For make few examples:

- It will request DNS for convert `www.google.com` into IP
- Maybe google can redirect you, for HTTPS for example
- Any node between you and the server can play in request time (proxy, QoS)

However, for troubleshoot your problem, I suggest you to use `traceroute` (ICMP) and `traceproto` to see latency between you, Google and every node between both. Example:

```
$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.40.135), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  par10s10-in-f7.1e100.net (173.194.40.135)  18.142 ms  18.116 ms  18.111 ms
```

But think in network communication, you must care to all elements of [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

Comment: I understand what you say but the confusion is that these nodes will be more or less same if I open google through browser or through python, then why does python take so long to connect and not my browser.